# Inlinable constant C array with no memory duplication

Tags: c, arrays, linker, constants

I want to declare a constant array which can be accessed from multiple C files and whose content can be inlined by the compiler, without duplicating the memory in multiple compilation units. Performance is critical in my application.

Exhibit 1:

```
header.h:
static const int arr[2] = { 1, 2 };

file1.c:
#include "header.h"
void file1() { printf("%d\n", arr[0]); }

file2.c:
#include "header.h"
int file2() { for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) printf("%d\n", arr[i]); }
```

In that case, the compiler can replace `arr[0]` by `1` in file1. However, since `arr` is declared `static const`, its memory is duplicated in both C files. AFAIK the C standard requires the array addresses to be different in both files. I have verified this under Linux by printing out the addresses. No linker consolidation occurs even with `-fmerge-all-constants` in gcc.

Exhibit 2:

```
header.h:
extern const int arr[2];

file1.c:
#include "header.h"
void file1() { printf("%d\n", arr[0]); }

file2.c:
#include "header.h"
const int arr[2] = { 1, 2 };
int file2() { for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) printf("%d\n", arr[i]); }
```

In that case, no memory duplication occurs but `arr[0]` is not inlined.

I consider the visibility scope defined by the C standard to be flawed. As such, a working solution under Linux/gcc which violates the C standard is acceptable to me.

Comment: Actually, `file2` also allows inlining the array.  `gcc -O9` unrolls the loop and directly pushes the two values.

Comment: @aschepler: Yes. On my system, with -O2, the compiler stops inlining once I set three or more elements in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you might try:

```
const int arr[2] __attribute__((weak)) = { 1, 2 };
```

Now the array still exists in every *.o object, but when those objects are linked together in a program, GNU `ld` will reduce them to just one common chunk of data.

If you don't already have such a thing, you may want in some common header file:

```
#ifndef __GNUC__
#define __attribute__(x)
#endif
```

Comment: Confirmed!! Inlining works and the array address is the same in each
file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There's no standard way to achieve that in "classic" C (referring to C89/90), unfortunately. In C89/90 you are limited to the two approaches you described, with their respective pros and cons, as long as you insist on using an array.

In C99 things are better. In C99 you can use so called *compound literals*, i.e. just define `arr` as a macro in the header file

```
#define arr ((const int []) { 1, 2 })
```

and then hope that the compiler will "inline" the array. Compound literals of `const` types are treated the same way as string literals: different occurrences of identical literal in the program can be merged by the compiler into one instance of the actual object (if the compiler doesn't inline it).

AFAIK, GCC compiler supports compound literals as an extension even in non-C99 modes.

Comment: I could not get your method to work. I get different (and invalid) values if I print out the "address" of the array directly. If I declare a function in each file that takes a pointer as argument and pass the array literal to each function, I also get different but valid pointer values. The array content is correct when I print it out in each function.

Comment: I also tried printing out the array values directly (without passing the pointer address). On disassembly, I see the compiler is actually storing all the array elements on the stack (mov 1, mov 2, etc) before printing out the values. Thanks for the help though, I didn't know about C99 array compound literals.

Comment: @Laurent Birtz: Compound literals are supposed to generate *local* objects when used in function scope and *static* objects when used in file scope. This implies that the values will indeed be stored "on the stack" from the abstract point of view. However, I'd expect the compiler to be able to optimize this out, i.e. to "inline" the array values and/or "merge" the different instances into one.

Comment: @Laurent Birtz: I'm not sure I understand why you care about the addresses. You were looking for an *inlinable* array, if I understood you correctly. This would immediately mean that you are not going to use that array in any way that would require its "instantiation". I.e. no address taking is allowed. Once you start taking addresses, "inlining" flies out the window right away.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I was looking for an array that can be inlined in contexts where it makes sense to do so (e.g. specific lookups) and still be usable in non-inlinable contexts (e.g. iterations), with no memory duplication even if the array is used in multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your analysis is somewhat wrong.  When you print the address of `arr`, you **force** the compiler to keep two copies around.  GCC will eliminate both copies if you don't do this.

A better way to determine what the linker has, and has not, eliminated is to look at the actual objects in the output file.  Under Linux, the `nm` program will tell you this.

If I compile your code (exhibit 1) with 'gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1':

```
gcc -std=c99 -g3 -O6 -fmerge-all-constants file1.c file2.c main.c
```

I then use `nm -a a.out | grep '\<arr\>'` to look for it in the symbol table:

```
$ nm -a a.out|grep '\<arr\>'|wc -l
0
```

In fact, if you try to find it in `gdb`, you find nothing:

```
(gdb) b file1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400540: file /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h, line 105.
(gdb) r
Starting program: a.out 
Breakpoint 1, file1 () at file1.c:5
5   void file1() { printf("%d\n", arr[0]); }
(gdb) print arr
$1 = <optimized out>
```

The compiler has completely optimized it out.

If I add `printf("%p\n",arr);` to the beginning of `file1()` and `file2()` and compile it the same way, then `nm -a a.out|grep '\<arr\>'` returns two references to `arr`:

```
$ nm -a a.out|grep '\<arr\>'|wc -l
2
$ nm -a a.out|grep '\<arr\>'
00000000004006c8 r arr
00000000004006d0 r arr
```

Comment: You are right, that gcc handles this special case cleverly, nowadays. But you are not proposing a real solution to the problem. First other compilers might treat that completely differently. Then, constants that you are not allowed to print are of quite restricted use.

Comment: @JensGustedt: The OP wanted a solution that worked for GCC and Linux.  In fact, any kind of inlining is compiler-dependent.  Even declaring a function `inline` is only a hint to the compiler; the C99 standard does not require that the function is actually inlined. This solution is a more general than you give it credit. Referring to the array's **values**, including printing these values, will still optimize the array away.  However, when you pass a pointer to an element, then the array has to actually exist, and the compiler is bound by the C99 `static` rules.

Comment: No offence intended. It is just that a solution to the problem exists. AndreyT's answer gives one, that perfectly works with gcc, but would work with other conforming compilers, too. Then, you are mistaken, `inline` is not a just "hint" but just a misnomer. It changes the visibility properties of the function. https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/myth-and-reality-about-inline-in-c99/

Comment: I confirm your information. However, there is still a duplication problem if there is one non-inlinable reference to the array in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selectany` [variable attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) and give your arrays external linkage (i.e. don't declare them `static`).  This will keep the array value in the header so that it can be inlined properly, and the `selectany` attribute will tell the linker to arbitrarily pick one of the definitions to be the real one and throw away the others (since they're all the same, it won't matter).

For example:

```
const int arr[] __attribute__((selectany)) = {1, 2};
```

---

**EDIT**: This apparently only works on Windows targets; the `weak` attribute did not work instead on a quick test I did with Cygwin's GCC, in that it produced multiple copies of the array in the resulting data segment.

Comment: gcc docs say: The `selectany` attribute is only available on Microsoft Windows targets.

Comment: D'oh, you're right.  It looks like the `weak` attribute doesn't work in a quick test I did -- it produced multiple copies of the array in the data segment.

Comment: Good to know it's possible to do it on Windows too. Thanks.